# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am trying to create a MEX file for a simple C function as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]);
int main()
{
    int x;
    int c;
    c=2;
    x=4;
    mexprintf ("the value for y is %d",c*x*x);

}
```

I saved the file as quad.c
But on Matlab, when I use the mex function

```
 mex quad.c
```

I receive an error:

```
 >> mex quadfinal.c
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction 
C:\Users\Oatmeel\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_UGPnwF\templib.x : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'quadfinal.mexw64' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

I properly included the mexFunction. I dont know where I am going wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]);
int main()
```

By this:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

Note there is no `;` at the end.

**EDIT:** also, `mexprintf` should be `mexPrintf`.

Comment: if I were to alter this so I can input the "x" when the mex file is executed in Matlab, how would I do so? I tried:
 
    #include <math.h>
    #include <mex.h>
    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,const         mxArray *prhs[])
    {
        int x;
        int c;
        c=2;
  
        mexPrintf( "please input x");
        scanf( "%d", x);
        mexPrintf ("the value for y is %d",c*x*x);
    
    }'

But it doesnt work. The mex file is properly created but when I  run the function it gives:
    please input xthe value for y is 44840450>>

Comment: I think a `mex` file cannot access stdin or stdout. If you want to input a value, you should do it via Matlab and pass it to the mex as a parameter.